# Creating a Generic method to load dataSet in cucumber using Poiji library

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

I have a class that loaded data from scenario steps
my first class is LoadUserStepDfn

```
public class LoadUserStepDfn extends LoadDataStepDfn<User> {

public LoadUserStepDfn(ReadingUserUsingPoiji readingUserUsingPoiji) {
    super.readingExcelUsingPoiji = readingUserUsingPoiji;
}

@Given("^Data is loaded from \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void data_is_loaded_from (String filePath) throws Throwable {
    super.data_is_loaded_from(filePath);
}
```

and it call class named LoadDataStepDfn

```
public class LoadDataStepDfn<T> {

public List<T> data;

protected ReadingExcelUsingPoiji readingExcelUsingPoiji;

public void data_is_loaded_from (String filePath) throws Throwable {
    data = readingExcelUsingPoiji.TransformExcelToClass(filePath);

}
```

and here is my class that reads Excel and stores it to java class

```
public abstract class ReadingExcelUsingPoiji<T> {


    public List<T> TransformExcelToClass(String filePath){
        PoijiOptions options = PoijiOptions.PoijiOptionsBuilder.settings().addListDelimiter(";").build();
        List<T> data = Poiji.fromExcel(new File(filePath), getMyType(), options);
        return data;
    }

    public abstract Class<T> getMyType();

}
```

the problem that I want to use one class I don't want it to be abstract and use another one which is this class

```
    public class ReadingUserUsingPoiji extends ReadingExcelUsingPoiji<User> {


    public Class<User> getMyType(){
        return User.class;
    }
```

Comment: Any class in Java can be extended (Without it being abstract, /or final)

Comment: hello thank you for replying 
here the resean why I use the secend class is i want to know the type of the object by ** getMyType **is there a way to do it in hte same class

Comment: Yes, your first class public ReadingExcelUsingPoiji will have a method that is implemented and return its type,

Then the class that extends will do extends ReadingExcelUsingPoiji  then @Override that parent method.   So your ReadingExcelUsingPoiji will return ReadingExcelUsingPoji.class, and your ReadingUserUsingPoiji  will return ReadingUserUsingPoiji .class from its method...or whatever you want

Comment: The idea of @override will work no matter if your parent class is abstract or not...

Comment: ah, I use ReadingExcelUsingPoiji to transofrm Excel file to Class Object for that i use ReadingExcelUsingPoiji to do the transformation but I need to pass the type of the class Object for my class User class so I creat another class called ReadingUserUsingPoiji just too get the type of User , what I want is to keep only ReadingExcelUsingPoiji and use it with any class Object generic method

Comment: in this line   List<T> data = Poiji.fromExcel(new File(filePath), getMyType(), options);

getMyType() return User is there a way to pass user generally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to understand here, so you dont want @override, but rather 1 method that returns you the type of class to transform to??

Why can't it be that simple...  You have a method that determines what class you should use to transform to...

I dont understand why you are using generics...your logic doesnt seem to really care for it? Especially if you have 1 ReadingExcelUsingPoiji class..it really shouldnt care.

```
public class ReadingExcelUsingPoiji<T> {

public List<T> transformExcelToClass(String filePath, Class<T> classToTransformTo) {
    PoijiOptions options = PoijiOptions.PoijiOptionsBuilder.settings().addListDelimiter(";").build();
    List<T> data = Poiji.fromExcel(new File(filePath), classToTransformTo, options);
    return data;
}


public static void main(String [] args) {
    
    ReadingExcelUsingPoiji genericConverter = new ReadingExcelUsingPoiji();
    
    List<User> listOfUsers = genericConverter.transformExcelToClass("yourFilePath", User.class);
    List<Car> listOfCars = genericConverter.transformExcelToClass("yourFilePath", Car.class);
}
```

}

```
public class LoadUserStepDfn extends LoadDataStepDfn<User> {

    
    
    @Given("^Data is loaded from \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void data_is_loaded_from (String filePath) throws Throwable {
        super.data_is_loaded_from(filePath , User.class);
    }

}




public class LoadDataStepDfn<T> {

    public List<T> data;

    protected ReadingExcelUsingPoiji readingExcelUsingPoiji;

    protected void data_is_loaded_from(String filePath, Class<T> classToTransformTo) throws Throwable {
        data = readingExcelUsingPoiji.transformExcelToClass(filePath, classToTransformTo);

    }

}
```

Comment: it gives me that error 
Required type:Class <T>Provided:Class<User>

and isUser variable where should I declare it

Comment: I updated my answer...can you see if that helps :)

Comment: In java method names start with lowerCase :)

Comment: I have an other class with is use this method ,there where i have a new error

`@When("^User login with the following username and password")
 public void user_login_with_the_following_username_and_password () throws Throwable {

  for (User user:loadDataStepDfn.data){
   login.enterUsername(user.getUsername());
   login.enterPassword(user.getPassword());
   login.clilckOnConection();
  }

 }`



in `User user:loadDataStepDfn.data` 

the error says 

Required 
type:Object 
Provided: User

Comment: Yay.  I am glad it helped